# why i'm getting zero instead of 1?

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, linear-search

This is a program of searching a number from linked list using recursion.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

class node { 
public: 
    int data; 
    node *next; 

    void create(int *,int); 
    int max(node*,int); 
}; 

node *first; 

void node::create(int a[],int n) { 
    first = new node; 
    first->data = a[0]; 
    first->next = NULL; 
    node *last = first; 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        node *t = new node; 
        t->data = a[i]; 
        t->next = NULL; 
        last->next = t; 
        last = t; 
    }
} 

int node::max(node *l, int p) { 
    if (l->data == p) { 
        return 1;
    } 
    if (l == 0) 
        return 0; 
    else {  
        max(l->next, p); 
        return 0;
    }
} 

int main() { 
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
    node m; 
    m.create(a,5); 
    cout << m.max(first, 3); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What is the `max` function actually supposed to do?  The name would suggest that it finds a maximum value, but it certainly doesn't do that.

Comment: On a hunch, though, look carefully at these two lines: `max(l->next, p); return 0;`    What exactly do they do, and is that what you want?

Comment: `if (l->data == p) { return 1; } if (l == 0) return 0; ...`  Should you really be using `l->data` before checking if `l == 0` ?  Dereferencing a null pointer is undefined behaviour and may cause time travel   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: Don't compare pointers to `0`. Compare to `nullptr` or `NULL`. Makes it apparent that `l` is a pointer in the context that it's used in.

Comment: @NateEldredge actually i just mistaken the standard name of search i.e i could have written search() instead of max() ?thanks for your valuable comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hunch.  Instead of this:

```
else {  
    max(l->next, p); 
    return 0;
}
```

This:

```
else {  
    return max(l->next, p); 
}
```

Or better yet, let's fix the whole `max` function to check for null before dereferencing `l` as well.

```
int node::max(node *l, int p) { 
    int result = 0;
    if (l != nullptr) {
       if (l->data == p) {
           result = 1;
       }
       else {
          result = max(l->next, p);
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @HarshdeepRaghuwanshi - if you found the answer provided helpful, don't forget to upvote or mark it as the accepted answer.